# How to back-up a database on IIS

Tags: database, mysql, iis

I've been having trouble finding a good tutorial on how to back-up a WordPress database using IIS as the web server. I installed WordPress using IIS's web platform installer and now I can't even find where the database file resides. I've been doing everything under a local development if that helps.

So my question is, how exactly do I back-up the database file associated with IIS?

Comment: Yes according to http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_on_Microsoft_IIS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the name of the database in word-press's wp-config.php file under the and was able to create a back-up of the file using MSQL workbench and the tutorial found here http://community.discountasp.net/showthread.php?t=11972.